# Intellij not respecting my android manifest settings

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have put

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml, yet I still Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). on my styles.xml. This started happening after I went to intellij from android studio. What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: I guess "it depends on your build target, not what is stated in the manifest."

Comment: Ah but on my project structure --> dependencies I have set the module SDK to API 19. And in my SDK I have set the build targets to android 4.4.2. This is really frustrating!